# What setting(s) determine whether PHP will throw an error on accessing an array using a non-existent index?

Tags: php, arrays, apache, iis-7

I'm trying to get a PHP 5 application working on IIS7.

This application appears to have been built under the assumption that accessing an array using an index that doesn't exist will simply return null, without raising an error and halting the program.

Given the following code:

```
<?PHP
  $testarray = array();
  print $testarray[1];
  print 'hello';
?>
```

When accessed through **Apache** (installed under WampServer), it will simply print "hello" on the screen, and ignore the error.

When accessed through **IIS 7**, it generates the following exception:

```
    PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in C:\Users\Jonathan\Projects\MyApp\api\inf.php on line 3
    PHP Stack trace:
    PHP   1. {main}() C:\Users\Jonathan\Projects\MyApp\api\inf.php:0
```

But if I comment out the first print statement, it executes correctly and displays "hello".

Both IIS and Apache are pointing to the same code-base, using the same instance of PHP (the version is 5.3.5) and the same PHP config.

Since this is a language issue, I don't see why it would matter what web-server I use, but I'm totally lost as to why one instance works when the other throws an error.

What setting might be responsible for this difference?

(If there's a way to configure IIS to be more lenient, I'd prefer that, rather than re-factoring the whole application to check arrays for indexes before accessing them.)

Comment: just do @print $testarray[1];

Comment: @miki That's a horrible idea. Everyone, please don't listen to him. Error suppression is wrong.

Comment: I guess it's like !important in CSS. Avoid it whenever possible.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ thanks for being an evangelist, but he only seemed to ask for a quick and dirty solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change this behavior by altering the [error reporting settings](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php) in php.ini.

You can set different levels of error reporting. For example, trying to access an undefined array index is an `E_NOTICE`. You can choose whether or not to display errors of this type. To see what the other levels are, see [this page.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php)

Any production website shouldn't display any errors whatsoever, while you should probably display *every* error in a development environment.

Comment: I thought it would be this too, but the thing is, both environments have the error mode set to E_ALL. I verified this by executing phpinfo() on both environments. So I don't see how it can be this setting causing the issue, unless IIS 7 is doing something different.

Comment: Actually I just ran it with 'error_reporting( E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE );' at the top, and now it works! So you're right about it being the error reporting settings. Unfortunately, that doesn't tell my why IIS is ignoring the php.ini settings. But anyway, at the thing is working now.

Comment: Ahh turns out IIS 7 was pointing to the correct PHP.INI but WAMP was pointing to the one in the Apache folder. (Which kinda makes sense.) So if I point them both to the same INI file, I should get consistent results.